# USB Drive with Mountain Lion Boot-Up Problem

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, startup

I've tried a few ways to restore the Mountain Lion InstallESD.dmg to a USB hard drive to reinstall on my Mac Mini. I've used Disk Utility Restore, Lion Disk Maker and Carbon Copy Cloner.

Each method gives me the same outcome: When booting I get the infamous circle with the slash and spinning gear.

I've tried to boot up with the same USB on multiple macs and they both have the same outcome. And yes, the Macs I'm trying it on have the compatibility to support Mountain Lion.

Comment: Can't you just [reinstall OS X from the recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11273)?

Comment: The old Hard Drive got the click of death and I put in a new one.

Comment: If you have a mid-2010 or later Mac mini and you installed [this firmware update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4904), you could also start up in Internet recovery mode.

Answer (score 1):

Saw your comment about replacing the HD, but could you report what the previous OS version was? I found that I couldn't upgrade from Leopord directly to Mountain Lion and had to upload to Snow Leopoard first. The machine in question was also in spec for ML.

Comment: I will try upgrading directly from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion.

Comment: Using an actual Snow Leopard Disk from Apple and running the install, the Mac Mini now Kernel Panics on boot-in. See here: http://i.imgur.com/PNxqH7r.jpg

Comment: It kernal panics on boot to SL after upgrade? On all machines?

Comment: It kernel panics while booting into the snow leopard install, it never makes it.